# Subtlety accessing and modifying a multidimensionnal list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

As I wrote a bit of code tonight, I came across a problem that even though it doesn't stop me, caught my attention for I couldn't figure it out. So here's a function I wrote (not supposed to be the optimal way to do it but nevermind...)

```
def ownShuffle( origin ):
    export  = [[] for i in range( len( origin ) ) ]
    indices = range( len( origin ) )
    for n, item in enumerate( origin ):
        i = random.randrange( len( indices ) )
        export[indices[i]] = item
        indices.remove(indices[i])
    return export
```

Now with a test sample like this:

```
c = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 5, 6], 
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

There is the problem part. I get different results with the almost same code.
If it write this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(c):
    c[i] = ownShuffle(line)

print c
>>> [[3, 2, 1],
     [6, 4, 5],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

I get a shuffled list. But with the following code:

```
for i, line in enumerate(c):
    line = ownShuffle(line)

print c
>>> [[1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 5, 6], 
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

I get the test sample unchanged. Perhaps it comes from the function I wrote? I have no idea...

So there goes my question: **Does anyone know why?**

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i, line in enumerate(c):
    line = ownShuffle(line)
```

You keep creating a temporary `line` but its not the same reference as your original list `c`. You would actually need to affect the values inside of `line` for it to reflect the original object.

You could see it changing the values inside of that same `line` by doing:

```py
for i, line in enumerate(c):
    line[:] = ownShuffle(line)
```

Here is a way to visualize what is happening:

```py
for i, line in enumerate(c):
    id_before = id(line)
    line = ownShuffle(line)
    print id_before, "=>", id(line)
# 4973032728 => 4973032656
# 4973034312 => 4973032656
# 4973034240 => 4973032656

for i, line in enumerate(c):
    id_before = id(line)
    line[:] = ownShuffle(line)
    print id_before, "=>", id(line)
# 4973032728 => 4973032728
# 4973034312 => 4973034312
# 4973034240 => 4973034240
```

In the first one you can see that its always a temporary object. Whereas in the second, the line is still the original line element from your `c`

Comment: `:` is how you index into the list, such as `c[1:5]`. By doing `line[:]` you are doing an "insert" over every element in the list with new elements. The actual object stays the same but you just set new values